# JQuery - Move Divs/Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of rows and I'm trying to do an onclick to select the row, then move it before or after it's sibling row.

I'm trying to use a series of `insertBefore()`, `insertAfter()`, `prev()`, and `next()` for selecting and moving elements. I'm not sure if these are good methods to use or if they're reaching their deprecation time or whatnot.

The code is below:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-10 medium-3 large-3 columns"><input type="text" placeholder="Presenter Name"></div>
        <div class="small-4 medium-1 large-1 text-center columns"></div>
        <div class="small-4 medium-1 large-1 text-center columns"></div>
        <div class="small-4 medium-1 large-1 text-center columns"></div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-5 large-5 columns"></div>
        <div class="show-for-medium-up medium-1 large-1 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-6 columns close-thik"></div>
            <div class="small-6 columns arrow">  
                <div class="arrow-up"></div>
                <div class="arrow-down"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-10 medium-3 large-3 columns"><input type="text" placeholder="Presenter Name"></div>
        <div class="small-4 medium-1 large-1 text-center columns"></div>
        <div class="small-4 medium-1 large-1 text-center columns"></div>
        <div class="small-4 medium-1 large-1 text-center columns"></div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-5 large-5 columns"></div>
        <div class="show-for-medium-up medium-1 large-1 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-6 columns close-thik"></div>
            <div class="small-6 columns arrow">  
                <div class="arrow-up"></div>
                <div class="arrow-down"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-10 medium-3 large-3 columns"><input type="text" placeholder="Presenter Name"></div>
        <div class="small-4 medium-1 large-1 text-center columns"></div>
        <div class="small-4 medium-1 large-1 text-center columns"></div>
        <div class="small-4 medium-1 large-1 text-center columns"></div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-5 large-5 columns"></div>
        <div class="show-for-medium-up medium-1 large-1 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-6 columns close-thik"></div>
            <div class="small-6 columns arrow">  
                <div class="arrow-up"></div>
                <div class="arrow-down"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there's a `<div>` with class *arrow* and two divs inside there that are the up and down arrow (for moving).

**JavaScript**

```
var MovePerson = {

    up: function() {

        $(document).on("click", ".arrow-up", function() {

            $(this).parents().eq(3).insertBefore($(this).prev());

        });

    }, 

    down: function() {

        $(document).on("click", ".arrow-down", function() {

            $(this).parents().eq(3).insertAfter($(this).next());

        });

    }

};

$(document).ready(MovePerson.up);
$(document).ready(MovePerson.down);
```

So if you can imagine, I have rows

```
A
B
C
D
```

And I want to move C to the second row, so order would then be `A, C, B, D`.

So my logic is to use `$(this).parents().eq(3)` to go to and select the `<row>` then use some more js to move it before or after the element .

(Bonus) It would be nice to know if I've reached the end or beginning. So perhaps some way of detecting if there's another sibling  after or before my target.

Comment: Don't you want to use any plugins to achieve this? It will be much easier to use plugnin.

Comment: While it's definitely possible to do this with just jquery, I'd recommend using a MVVM framework like knockout.js. That way knockout handles binding to the DOM, and your reorder function would just reorder the array using `splice`. If the array was an observable array bound to the page, knockout would automatically re-render whatever elements changed.

Comment: Well, this is part of an Angular app, but the only things I saw were over-complex addins with poorly written directions. I was thinking maybe a quick/dirty solution would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the idea is just to simply to select current row, identify the prev/next row, detach the current row and either slot it before previous row or after next row.

Here is a quick mode to your code snippet.

```
var MovePerson = {

    up: function() {

        $(document).on("click", ".arrow-up", function() {

            var thisRow = $(this).parents().eq(3);
            var prevRow = $(thisRow).prev();

            //we only want to move this row up if there is a row before this row.
            if(prevRow){
                $(prevRow).before($(thisRow).detach());
            }
        });

    }, 

    down: function() {

        $(document).on("click", ".arrow-down", function() {

            var thisRow = $(this).parents().eq(3);
            var nextRow = $(thisRow).next();

            //we only want to move this row down if there is a row after this row.
            if(nextRow){
                $(nextRow).after($(thisRow).detach());
            }
        });

    }

};

$(document).ready(MovePerson.up);
$(document).ready(MovePerson.down);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it works exactly how I'd like, and with the bonus content. Do you think applying some kind of animation to this would be simple? So that the move of the div isn't so choppy?

Comment: @Kenny you can try calling a slideUp() + detach(),  then before/after followed by a slideDown()